# What is normalized winning frequency in kernel self organizing map(SOM)?

Tags: clustering, k-means, kernel

In the k-means based kernel SOM, proposed by MacDonald and Fyfe (2000), the update of the mean is based on a soft learning algorithm

`mi(t + 1) = mi(t) + Λ[φ(x) − mi(t)]`

where Λ is the normalized winning frequency of the i-the mean and is defined
[image]

where ζ is the winning counter and is often defined as a
Gaussian function between the indexes of the two neurons. (Reference: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/hujun.yin/pubs/NN-SI-2006-Yin.pdf

I want to know how the normalized winning frequency is calculated. If possible, can someone link a reference that explains the notation?

Comment: This would be better suited at Stats SE, aka [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).